# Margins on LinearLayout cut off from top, bottom, left and right. Can't find a fix

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-linearlayout, margin

I have a `LinearLayout` which has its margins cut off and I've tried fiddling around with the XML as well as the `FlyOutContainer` class in order to fix it, no luck.

I want my `LinearLayout` to fit on any android screen. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this problem? And can anyone explain to me why the margins are being cut off, so if this happens again I know what to do?

Here is what my `LinearLayout` menu looks like:

[image]

Here is the `FlyOutContainer` class:

```
public class FlyOutContainer extends LinearLayout {

private View menu; //Menu of application
private View content; //Content of application

protected static final int menuMargin = 150; 

public enum MenuState {
    CLOSED, OPEN
};

protected int currentContentOffset = 0;
protected MenuState menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;

public FlyOutContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public FlyOutContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public FlyOutContainer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    this.menu = this.getChildAt(0);

    this.content = this.getChildAt(1);
    this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    if (changed)
        this.calculateChildDimensions();

    this.menu.layout(left, top, right - menuMargin, bottom);

    this.content.layout(left + this.currentContentOffset, top, right
            + this.currentContentOffset, bottom);

}
public void toggleMenu() {
    switch (this.menuCurrentState) {
    case CLOSED:
        this.menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.currentContentOffset = this.getMenuWidth();
        this.content.offsetLeftAndRight(currentContentOffset);          this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPEN;
        break;

    case OPEN:
        this.content.offsetLeftAndRight(-currentContentOffset);
        this.currentContentOffset = 0;
        this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSED;
        this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
    this.invalidate();
}

private int getMenuWidth() {
    return this.menu.getLayoutParams().width;
}

private void calculateChildDimensions() {
    this.content.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
    this.content.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth();

    this.menu.getLayoutParams().width = this.getWidth() - menuMargin;
    this.menu.getLayoutParams().height = this.getHeight();
}

}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<FlyOutContainer.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
style="@style/Container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_Child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    facebook:is_cropped="true"
    facebook:preset_size="small" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/button_1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/button_2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/button_3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/button_4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/button_5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/button_6" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/defined_Text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="@string/Toggle_Menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem by taking out `style="@style/Container` out of my XML, for some weird reason my theme which is custom made was making extra padding on all four sides of the Layout.

So in summary changing XML to this fixed it:

```
<FlyOutContainer.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

....

....

....

</FlyOutContainer.FlyOutContainer>
```

**IMPROVED ANSWER:**

What's the point of UI design if you can't keep your background right :) ? In order to keep the style I had previously implemented I saw that in my `styles.xml` in `res` there was an extra padding of this 16 dp like so:

```
<style name="Container" >
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item> <!-- REMOVE HERE!!! -->
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

removing that line allowed me to keep my background

[image]